# Is there a way to use ParseJS User.signUp() without becoming the user

Tags: parse-platform

In the [ParseJS docs](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/master/Parse.User.html#signUp), you use `Parse.User.signUp()` to create a new user, instead of user.save() like other objects. The Parse server will encrypt the password, check user/email doesn't exist etc. before creating the user ... which is all fine.

But when the response is returned the JS client 'becomes' the new user. This is fine when someone is signing themselves up ... but when an administrator of a multi-user app is creating multiple users to access their account, this logic doesn't work.

```
// admin/users/add
- logged in admin creates a new user w/ create()

async create () {
  const response = await Parse.User.signUp()
  //- response is the new user ... but oh dear - the admin who was adding a new user has magically BECOME the new user as well!
}
```

I haven't seen such a thing in the docs but is there perhaps known (or undocumented) way to prevent the user who is creating new users from becoming the new user(s)?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out after some discussion with a core team member that no, this is not possible.

The best alternative for me was to create a cloud function which ran the `Parse.User.signUp(...)`